# Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installation stuck

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

So first i tried online and then offline installation of the same but it got stuck
at installing Hotfix for Windows (KB2882822).

Comment: Thankyou guys. I stopped the installation and restarted it and it installed successfully on second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it looks like the VS installer stuck on the same point ‘Hotfix for Windows (KB2882822)’, you can have a try with the following:

1. Go to windows update and install all pending patches, reboot the computer, then re-run the VS installer
2. If your OS is Windows 7 SP1, manually download the update KB2882822: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=40371 and install it, then restart the computer and re-run the VS installer
3. Disable your anti-virus and anti-spyware software, clean up the %temp% folder, then run the installer as administrator.
4. Turing off the internet connection, then re-run the VS installer as administrator
5. Open the Task Manager in detail mode, look for a sub-installer process that showing 0% CPU usage and 0% disk usage, indicating it has died. Then just kill that process and the master installation will resume. Or open Task Manager in detail mode--> Go to the "Details" tab--> Right Click the VisualStudio Process-->Click on the "Analyze wait chain". You will see the name of the process which is responsible for the wait. Kill this process and the installation maybe process quickly.
6. When it gets stuck during installation, cancel it, but don’t uninstall. Go to the Control PanelPrograms and Features and select repair VS.